# Increment value with transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, transactions

I'm developing asp.net core application with EF and MsSql. I want to increment some field and be shure its incremented correctly.

For example: tread1 increment value from 10 by 2, thread2 increment same field by 1. 
Result must be **13**. But in fact I get 11, couse thread2 get data before thread1 commited and thread2 commited after thread1.

Example code:

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var context = new MyContext())
                {
                    context.Database.Migrate();
                    context.Books.Add(new Book {Amount = 10});
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }


                var context1 = new MyContext();
                var context2 = new MyContext();

                var transaction1 = context1.Database.BeginTransaction();
                var transaction2 = context2.Database.BeginTransaction();

                var book1 = context1.Books.Single();
                var book2 = context2.Books.Single();

                book1.Amount += 2;
                //some other changes with entities here, so i need transactions

                book2.Amount += 1;
                //some other changes with entities here, so i need transactions

                context1.SaveChanges();
                transaction1.Commit();

                context2.SaveChanges();
                transaction2.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            var result = new MyContext().Books.Single().Amount;
            Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=CashboxDomain1;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
        }
    }

    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Amount { get; set; }
    }
```

My application is mutltithread and i need transactions.

Is there any way to get wright increment?

Performance is important for me. Is there any faster method then optimistic concurrency + reload data on error?

Comment: Why do you have two copies of your context? That's going to be a problem, no matter what. Each context instance keeps its own internal object cache and change tracking, so you're going to inevitably get out of sync and end up overwriting changes from one to the other.

Comment: i make two copies to show that's in fact i really have two contexts: it's web-api service

Comment: Yes, but they're two independent representations of the same underlying data store. What you do to one affects the data store, but not the other, leaving each in an inconsistent state.

Comment: nothing for now, that's why i ask. I have few ways and now thinking, which one is best

Answer (score 1):

Check out this article here: https://www.bogotobogo.com/CSharp/csharp_multithreading3.php

If you make use of the [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) keyword to handle the concurrency issue you are having.
Share the lock object between the two threads and you will make sure one is executed after the other.

Answer (score 1):

While you can utilize locks/semaphores, that's going to actually be worse performance-wise than optimistic concurrency. The only way to make the previous work is by essentially creating a choke point where only one update can proceed at a time. Using optimistic concurrency, you can maintain parallelism, and for the most part, there won't actually be any issues. On the what should be relatively rare occasions there is a concurrency conflict, the worst of it is that you might need to refresh from the database and submit the update again. Unless your database is severely under-optimized, neither of those operations should take any significant time, and the performance impact overall will be relatively minimal. While it's theoretically possible that multiple loops may be required to finally get the update in, in practice this is going to virtually never happen. If the system is performant enough, concurrency conflicts are pretty rare to begin with (just not rare enough to discount completely); the odds of a single request hitting a conflict multiple times in a row, is infinitesimally small.